# Udev not working

Tags: udev

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1337", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/New.sh"
```

script:

```
#!/bin/sh

vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

`udevadm` test shows that it runs the script but nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [libudev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html), that could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Saying that they *could* use something isn't an Answer; *how* would they use it to solve *their* problem?